# Javascript splitting negative number and removing negative

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a problem while I'm trying to split an integer in to digits with negative number
let's say -88 converting them to string wound be [-,8 ,8]
and my goal is to remove the '-' and add both digits to get 16 but the problem is that negative

Here is my code:

```
function sumDigits(number) {
    var digits = (""+number).split("");
    var sum = 0;
    for( var i = 0; i < digits.length; i++){

      var test = parseInt(digits[i]);
      sum = sum + test;
      }
    return sum;
    }
```

Comment: but your function does not provide `16` when pass `sumDigits(88)`

Comment: There are enough other threads here which could help you.

Comment: Thank you for your replays I will see which one fixes my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works with -88:

```
   var digits =number + "";
   var sum = 0;
   for( var i = 0; i < digits.length; i++){

      var test = parseInt(digits[i]);

      if(!isNaN(test))
         sum = sum + test;
      }
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer I didn't know that isNan() existed in the first place ;)

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for the absolute value of the number? Maybe this would work.

```
function sumDigits(number) {
    number = Math.abs(number);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function sumDigits(number) {
    number = (number < 0) ? number*-1 : number;
    var digits = (""+number).split("");
    var sum = 0;
    for( var i = 0; i < digits.length; i++){

      var test = parseInt(digits[i]);
      sum = sum + test;
      }
    return sum;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add this at the start of your function

```
if (number < 0) {
    number *= -1;
}
```

As mentioned in at least one other answer

```
number = Math.abs(number);
```

will also work

Answer (score 1):

Quick and Dirty:

```
function sumDigits(number){
    number=(number<0)?-number:number;
    return (number+"").split("").reduce(function(o,n){ return o*1+n*1 },"0");
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FP6Y5/)